# Split number into n different parts with decreasing trend?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, optimization, divisibility

I want to split a number into n parts. But, the values should follow decreasing pattern.

For example, let's say I have a number `10` and I want to divide them by `3`. So, it could be `5, 3, 2.` If I want to divide `10` by `5`, then it could be `4, 3 , 2, 1, 0`.

So, it should divide all the number into different parts with decreasing trend. In other words, I divided by N = X; X = x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + xn; Where I is input number and N is divisor and the condition is xi>=xi+1.

The decrease distribution should follow such that, middle number will be approximately equal to normal division. For, the above example, 10/3 = 3.33 and 3 is the middle number for the first output. Similarly, 10/5 = 2 and 2 is the middle number for the second series.

Is there any mathematical formula available for this problem. I couldn't find any similar result results on internet. Any help would be appreciable. If you need more details about the problem, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you allow negative numbers? What to do when middle number is much smaller than number of parts? Say $30$ into $15$ parts? Or how do you define middle when the number of parts is even? This is not clear nor always possible as it stands now. But for reference, "Split number $n$ into $k$ different parts" is called a [partition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Partition.html). Another way of saying "strictly decreasing trend"  is to say that all parts are distinct (because you can always sort them later).  See [Partition Function $Q(n,k)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html).